# Restoring Windows

Tags: partitioning, windows-8, raid

I have been trying to get Ubuntu to work on my laptop for the last few days. I have been extremely unsuccessful in doing so.

All I want to do at this point is to get Windows back.

I have an exact copy of all the files that were on my Windows partition before I tried to remove everything and install Ubuntu using the installer (which failed).

I have tried using my other Windows computer to create a recovery USB and using it to reset my laptop, but it gives me an error saying a required partition is missing.

I can no longer even use an Ubuntu USB as it will not boot from it.

One thing that I think is key is that at one point when I used the Ubuntu USB to check disc for errors, it said 2 files had errors.
I used GParted to try to get rid of what Ubuntu partitions were installed and came across three left.
One was a long name that started with "/dev/" (about the size of my ssd, 128GB), and the other two were "/dev/sda/" and "/dev/sdb/", which were about 45 GB each. I removed all partitions from the large one and the two small ones had errors saying that GParted did not recognize the name or something.
Somehow, through me messing things up, the big one disappeared.

When I boot my computer in Legacy mode, it shows a quick menu saying press ctrl+i to edit and it shows 2 things that I think are what the "/dev/sda" and "/dev/sdb" are.
Pressing ctrl+i takes you to an intel RAID system editor. You can create a RAID system or delete one, but only the option to create one is available for me.

How can I recover Windows?

Comment: Weren't you the one that asked for cloning the Windows drive as a backup?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question, you've probably deleted your Windows recovery partition by now.

The best you can do now is to boot your Windows recovery CD/DVD.  If you don't have one, but still have your product key, download it from Microsoft.  If you don't have your product key, turn your laptop upside down and look for it there.

Furthermore, here on Ask Ubuntu, we have some people that still dual-boot between Ubuntu and Windows, but the real Windows experts are on http://superuser.com, a sister site of AskUbuntu. I'll flag this question for it to be migrated there.